# Why is value of CMD for PID 1 different depending on the flags passed to ps?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ps

`ps -ef | grep -E 'PID|init'` and `ps -p 1` report different strings for the `CMD` column of ps output. Why is one `systemd` and the other `/sbin/init`? I would have expected to just see `/sbin/init`. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

```
user@host:~$ ps -ef | grep -E 'PID|init' --color=no
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 15:07 ?        00:00:13 /sbin/init splash
bag      22919  8273  0 19:52 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -E PID|init --color=no
user@host:~$ ps -p 1
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:13 systemd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two "CMD" fields: one taken from the actual command line aka `argv[0]`, and a separate field named `comm`.

Usually the `comm` field contains the program's filename (up to 15 bytes, anyway) but systemd deliberately overwrites this value to make it easier to determine which init system is currently active.

In predefined outputs, both fields have the same column name. However, `ps -p` shows the comm field while regular `ps` and `ps -f` show the argv[] or command line.

(Linux 'ps' is an unholy combination of BSD 'ps' and SysV 'ps' – depending on the combination of options you might get SysV-like output or BSD-like output or something entirely different.)